# Пустой список в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как узнать, что список пуст ? В некоторых случаях такой подход

```
    if len(lst) == 0:
       return 1
```

может привести к ошибке. Как это сделать правильно ?

Comment: Обычный `if not lst:` не подходит?

Comment: Эм, а можно пример такой ошибки? Если lst действительно список и действительно пуст, то данный код обязан работать, а вы наверно что-то делаете не так с самой переменной.

Comment: @andreymal может топикастер переживает, что кто-то напишет `def len(a): return 1` ?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian в таком случае есть куча более серьёзных поводов для беспокойства :D

Comment: @andreymal это да ). Для junior кстати не такая уж и гипотетическая ситуация. Например использование built-in имен типа `file` для своих переменных встречается довольно часто.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian `file` нет в Питоне 3 и даже в Питоне 2 в *подавляющем* числе случаев следует `open` вместо `file` использовать. Это слишком хорошее имя, чтобы его совсем не использовать, поэтому переопределять `file` это совершенно нормально. Но это исключение—в общем случае не следует встроенные имена переопределять для несвязанных целей.

Comment: @jfs и это очень хорошо, что в 3 освободили его, но в 2-ке все таки не стоит перекрывать. Мало ли потом кто-то закопипастит далее по контексту код, который ждет оригинальную ф-ию.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я вам говорю про практику, а не теорию. На практике, либо исходный код должен заменить file на open,  либо такой проблемы как "я скопипастил код не читая и он моё узко-специальное использование file сломал" просто не существует.

Comment: @jfs как минимум линтеры с вами не согласны

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds))

Comment: @jfs не нашел там про перекрытие built-in имен. Ну что же, если вы верите, что это хорошая практика, вы наверное найдете и в талмуде подтверждение. Мое скромное мнение - не переопределять встроенные имена.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40039/discussion-between-jfs-and-vladimir-gamalian).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> В отличие от некоторых языков программирования, в Python объект считается false, только если он пуст. Это значит, что не нужно проверять длину строки, кортежа или словаря — достаточно проверить его как логическое выражение.

Взято [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/85238/), может чего еще полезного найдете.

Поэтому предложенный в комментарии вариант @Vladimir Gamalian думаю подходит:

```
if not lst:
```